# laravel5 как получить объект ошибки throttle в handler

Tags: php, laravel

К примеру есть роут:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'throttle'], function () {
Route::get('people', function () {
    return Person::all();
});});
```

Как словить ошибку throttle в классе Handler?

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
        if ($e instanceof TooManyRequestsHttpException) {
          //получить здесь
       }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```